# pyserialでループが止まらない

Tags: python, python3

いま「自動でBreak信号を送り、プロンプトが返ってきたら処理を終えなさい」
というコードを考えています。

その中で「プロンプトが返ってきたら処理を終えなさい」の記述が出来ないでいます。
どの様にコードを書いたら止まるのでしょうか。
ご教示の程、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

**環境**
Python   3.6.8 
pyserial　3.4

```
import sys
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(
    　port='COM1',
    　baudrate=115200,          
    　parity='N',             
    　stopbits=1,
    　bytesize=8,
    　timeout=8
      )

ser.isOpen()

while True:
    ser.send_break()

    command = '\r\n'
    out = ser.readline()
    out = out.decode("utf-8", "ignore")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    if out == '>':
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: 通信相手のソフト/ハードは何で、BREAKがどう扱われるかの仕様は確認していますか？ [シリアル通信について](https://users.atmark-techno.com/forum/armadillo/879), [Receive/read BREAK condition on Linux serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803434/receive-read-break-condition-on-linux-serial-port), [Windowsのシリアル通信でBREAK信号を送受信する](http://bamch0h.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/07/17/012103) なお、単純に毎回の受信データを`print()`することでも、自分側の状況は確認出来ますよ。

Comment: ご教示頂きましてありがとうございます。リンク先の情報を確認して、挑戦してみます。

Answer (score 1):

> ser.isOpen()

シリアルポートがOpenされていないのでは。

Comment: おお！ それでしょうね。見ていて気付きませんでした。

Comment: ご教示頂きましてありがとうございます。仰る通りでした。無事処理できる様になりました。